# PDFs generated with iTextSharp generated watermark giving error

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

We are applying a watermark using iTextSharp to PDF documents before passing them to client. On some machines (all using v.11 of PDF viewer), the following error is being displayed.

**An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF Document to correct the problem.**

The watermarking code is as follows:

```
protected static byte[] GetStampedDocument(byte[] content, string mark, string heading)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);

                PdfContentByte pdfPageContents = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
                pdfPageContents.BeginText(); 

                PdfGState gstate = new PdfGState();
                gstate.FillOpacity = 0.2f;
                gstate.StrokeOpacity = 0.3f;

                pdfPageContents.SaveState();
                pdfPageContents.SetGState(gstate);

                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName, false);
                pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 46);
                pdfPageContents.SetRGBColorFill(32, 32, 32);

                pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, mark, pageSize.Width / 2, pageSize.Height / 2, 66);

                if (heading != null && heading.Length > 0)
                {
                    pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
                    pdfPageContents.SetRGBColorFill(32, 32, 32); 
                    pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, heading, 5, pageSize.Height - 15, 0);
                }

                pdfPageContents.EndText();
                pdfPageContents.RestoreState();
            }

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true; 
            pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true; 
            pdfStamper.Close(); 
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I cannot recreate this on any machine I have tried so there is an environmental element to this as well I expect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save the graphics state inside a text object:

```
pdfPageContents.BeginText(); 
[...]
pdfPageContents.SaveState();
[...]
pdfPageContents.EndText();
pdfPageContents.RestoreState();
```

This is not allowed, cf. Figure 9 — Graphics objects — in ISO 32000-2, special graphics state operators (like saving or restoring the graphics state) may not be used inside a text object.

To prevent this invalid syntax, move `pdfPageContents.SaveState()` before `pdfPageContents.BeginText()`. This furthermore makes the nesting of saving/restoring the state and beginning and ending the text object more natural.